# Asp.net MVC routing ambiguous, two paths for same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying out ASP.NET MVC routing and have of course stumbled across a problem. I have a section, /Admin/Pages/, and this is also accessible through /Pages/, which it shouldn't. What could I be missing?

The routing code in global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Pages",    // Route name
            "Admin/Pages/{action}/{id}",  // URL with parameters
            // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = "Pages", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",   // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",   // URL with parameters
             // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
        );

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest adding an explicit route for /Pages/ at the beginning.

The problem is that it's being handled by the Default route and deriving:

controller = "Pages"
action = "Index"
id = ""

which are exactly the same as the parameters for your Admin route.

Answer (score 7):

For routing issues like this, you should try out my [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) assembly (use only in testing). It can help figure out these types of issues.

P.S. If you're trying to secure the Pages controller, make sure to use the [Authorize] attribute. Don't just rely on URL authorization.

Comment: This should be the answer because the intent is to secure the Index action method of the PagesController.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a constraint to the default rule so that the {Controller} tag cannot be "Pages".

Answer (score 0):

You have in you first route {action} token/parameter which gets in conflict with setting of default action. Try changing parameter name in your route, or remove default action name.